# WebDriver wait n seconds

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, chai

I am writing some functional tests with Sauce Labs (Using Selenium + Webdriver + Nodejs). One of my test cases looks like the following:

```
  it('Should Not Have Any Errors', function(done) {
        browser
            .get(host + '/test.live.cgi?view=pixelTest')
            .elementById('errorHolder')
            .text()
            .should.eventually.equal('[]')
            .nodeify(done);
   });
```

How would I go about waiting 10 seconds between loading the page and checking the errorHolder element's text? I have been scanning through the api https://github.com/admc/wd/blob/master/doc/api.md but all of the wait functions look like they require an asserter function to test whether a given condition is true. I am trying to use `waitFor(opts, cb) -> cb(err)` method but I am unsure of how to chain it with the promises. Can I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Found the answer in the sleep function provided by webdriver. Now the code looks like this:

```
it('Should Not Have Any Errors', function(done) {
        browser
            .get(host + '/test.live.cgi?view=pixelTest')
            .sleep(10000)
            .elementById('errorHolder')
            .text()
            .should.eventually.equal('[]')
            .nodeify(done);
  });
```

Comment: sleep is the right answer, I used it from the driver itself await driver.sleep(2000);

Answer (score 13):

```js
await driver.sleep(n * 1000)
```

The above code works for me. Make sure that this code is inside an async function.

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
.delay(10)
```

If you really have to use a delay though, consider defining it as a variable. You will have more control over delays throughout your code and it will be easier to search for if you need to refactor.

Edit to add:

you can also use:

```
.then(function () {
    browser.waitForElementById('errorHolder');
})
```

Comment: Didn't work. Test threw an error: object has no method delay